# Azure point-to-site vpn with password or 2-factor authentication

Tags: vpn, azure

I have configured a virtual network and virtual network gateway. I can successfully connect to the VPN using the package provided and this allows me access to the private IP for RDP login.

Is there a way i can achieve the same functionality except it requires two factor authentication to join the VPN?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only authenticate Azure VPN P2S through the use of certificates. Atm there's no way to add MFA as it would require integration with Azure AD first. Probably it's not going to happen since this feature is in review since 2014.

[Provide multi-factor authentication capabilities in VPN client](http://feedback.azure.com/forums/217313-azure-networking/suggestions/5314840-provide-multi-factor-authentication-capabilities-i)

However, you can use MFA Server to MFA Windows Server RDP logins.

[Choose the Azure Multi-Factor Authentication solution for you](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/multi-factor-authentication/multi-factor-authentication-get-started)

**Update**: This has now been implemented and can be accomplished by using the NPS Server extension for Azure.

[Integrate your VPN infrastructure with Azure MFA by using the Network Policy Server extension for Azure](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/authentication/howto-mfa-nps-extension-vpn)